# React-bootstrap Navbar example doesn't register clicks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

Using the [Navbar example](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components.html#navbars) in my code, it renders fine but everything apart from the Header component doesn't respond to clicks. The dropdown doesn't dropdown, the links don't take me anywhere. Happens both on mobile and desktop. I'm using `react v14.8`, does that affect anything? I know the latest version is 15 but I have to keep it at 14 to support another library I'm using...

```js
import * as React from "react";
import * as ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import * as _ from "lodash";

var firebase = require('firebase');
var firebaseui = require('firebaseui');
import {Navbar, Nav, NavItem, NavDropdown, Button, Jumbotron, MenuItem} from 'react-bootstrap';

export class App extends React.Component<any, any> {

   constructor() {
     super();

 }

 render() {

     return (
      <Navbar>
     <Navbar.Header>
       <Navbar.Brand>
         <a href="#">React-Bootstrap</a>
       </Navbar.Brand>
     </Navbar.Header>
     <Nav>
       <NavItem eventKey={1} href="#">Link</NavItem>
       <NavItem eventKey={2} href="#">Link</NavItem>
       <NavDropdown eventKey={3} title="Dropdown" id="basic-nav-dropdown">
         <MenuItem eventKey={3.1}>Action</MenuItem>
         <MenuItem eventKey={3.2}>Another action</MenuItem>
         <MenuItem eventKey={3.3}>Something else here</MenuItem>
         <MenuItem divider />
         <MenuItem eventKey={3.3}>Separated link</MenuItem>
       </NavDropdown>
     </Nav>
   </Navbar>
     );
 }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

This is literally everything in my code. My index.html has a div with the id 'app' that it's getting rendered to. Nothing here should not be working, but for some reason, it's broken.

Oh, I should mention; no errors in Chrome Dev Tools console, pausing on exceptions doesn't catch any exceptions when clicking the unresponsive items. Completely silent and utter failure.

edit: here's my package.json for some installing shenanigans: http://pastebin.com/zYZQFRa5

Comment: did you mess with the css?

Comment: No? I'm linking to the bootstrap css and the optional theme css in my index.html file, that's it.

Comment: I installed this and used your exact code and its working just find so it must be your build.

Comment: Yes. I just did too and it's working perfectly fine. What other libraries are you using? Maybe that's conflicting?

Comment: Link your packages.json or create a new app folder using create-react-app and start over. I bet something is up with your babel install

Comment: Bloody heck. I had to do a node-module delete and `npm i` to even get react-bootstrap imports working correctly, so I don't know why this is acting up. Here's my package.json: http://pastebin.com/zYZQFRa5. It's full of a lot of stuff I've installed and no longer use, yeah, I should probably uninstall that.

Comment: @Chase I tried removing some of my extraneous installed modules, also tried upgrading react and react-dom to v15.0.1, still didn't make a difference. Is there anything in my package.json that's obviously conflicting?